# How to manage local job in RStudio

Tags: r, parallel-processing, rstudio, local

I am currently using a local job source in RStudio to run multiple scripts on the RStudio Server. However, the number of jobs that are currently running is different from that is shown in the console.

[image]

It has only 6 running jobs actually, but it says 44 jobs like this

[image]

How to remove the failed running script or stop it so that the number of jobs running is reduced?